# json_decode to use API in wrapper class doesn't produce output

Tags: php, curl

I need an help for  displaying a JSON code in this code actually when I run it get an empty page but I want to get a json code result but am not getting I just wanna see how to get it

Code :-

```
<?php
class Api
{
    const API_URL = 'http://yoursite/api/v2'; // API URL/Replace reseller domain
    const API_TOKEN = ''; // Your API token

    public function order($data) { // add order
        $post = array_merge([
            'api_token' => self::API_TOKEN,
            'action' => 'add'
        ], $data);

        return json_decode($this->connect($post));
    }

    public function status($order_id) { // get order status
        return json_decode($this->connect([
            'api_token' => self::API_TOKEN,
            'action' => 'status',
            'order' => $order_id
        ]));
    }

    public function balance() { // get balance
        return json_decode($this->connect([
            'api_token' => self::API_TOKEN,
            'action' => 'balance',
        ]));
    }

   public function packages() { // get packages list
        return json_decode($this->connect([
            'api_token' => self::API_TOKEN,
            'action' => 'packages',
        ]));
    }

    private function connect($post) {
        $_post = Array();
        foreach ($post as $name => $value) {
            $_post[$name] = urlencode($value);
        }

        $ch = curl_init(self::API_URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch) != 0 && empty($result)) {
            $result = false;
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
}

// Examples

$api = new Api();

// Fetch Packages
$packages = $api->packages();

// Check balance
$balance = $api->balance();

// Add order
$order = $api->order(array('package' => 1, 'link' => 'http://example/link', 'quantity' => 100));

// Add Custom comments order
$order = $api->order(array('package' => 11, 'link' => 'http://example/link', 'quantity' => 4, 'comments' => "good pic\ngreat photo\n:)\n;)")); # Custom Comments

// Check Order status
$status = $api->status($order->order);
```

In this code am just getting a blank page but I want to output the
Public function balance ()
I wanna output the JSON response just help mep
Me

How to output it's json_decode?
Please help me

Comment: It makes sense that you're getting a blank page. You're assigning the results of the method calls to variables, but you aren't actually printing them, unless there's some other code that isn't shown here.

Comment: there's no `echo` or anything similar, so nothing will be shown. I suppose you want to add `echo $order;` (after you have placed one). Same for `$balance`, `$status`,.. _EDIT_: I missread json_decode as json_encode. So you cant echo $order that way I said...

Comment: Depending on the data that the API returns to you for the various calls, json_decode may produce an array or an object that you won't be able to just echo out, you'll need to echo a specific key or property.

Comment: [nitpick] You should also make the URL and Token class properties rather than constants, and have them specified them in the constructor. This way you don't have to duplicate or edit the class definition just to use a different URL or Token.

Comment: "Blank page" means check your server error logs because you're probably getting a *bunch* of them.

Answer (score 0):

As comments have said, you need to output a Variable.

```
print_r($order);
print_r($status);
```

I'm using print_r because it gives you a nice display of an Array value. Which is most likely what you are gonna get back from your json_decode.

**Side note:** The current way you are using json_decode you will have to refer to variables like

```
$order->id
```

But if you want to access them as arrays

```
$order['id']
```

Then you need to use json_decode like this

```
json_decode($json, true); // The True value is important
```

[PHP docs json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)